# Remove rows dominated by any value where age is higher/lower

Tags: r, ggplot2

-1
I have a dataframe with two columns, age and performance, with one observation for each age. I want to remove all rows where the performance value is lower than any performance where age is higher. But only if age is higher than the age of the max performance. How to do that?

Sample dataframe:

```
structure(list(age = c(31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 
57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 
73, 74), performance = c(3.2341087962963, 3.13613425925926, 3.1553125, 
3.22259259259259, 3.11091435185185, 3.41855324074074, 3.21152777777778, 
3.12123842592593, 3.49372685185185, 3.69923611111111, 3.51280092592593, 
3.30284722222222, 3.09113425925926, 3.01299768518518, 3.05696759259259, 
3.3383912037037, 3.1884837962963, 3.00399305555556, 3.01096064814815, 
3.0466087962963, 3.06674768518519, 3.05023148148148, 3.0993287037037, 
2.84232638888889, 2.90362268518519, 2.82956018518519, 3.02834490740741, 
2.74263888888889, 2.87833333333333, 2.56236111111111, 2.73252314814815, 
2.48283564814815, 2.7869212962963, 2.50503472222222, 2.46137731481481, 
2.4915162037037, 2.4375, 2.12164351851852, 2.413125, 2.38354166666667, 
2.08234953703704, 1.77328703703704, 1.87770833333333, 2.00084490740741
)), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = "data.frame")
```

To make it more complicated though, I want to do the contrary up to the maximum performance. That is, when age is lower than the age of the max performance, then I want to remove the rows where performance is lower than any performance where age is lower.

This is how the scatter plot looks with all values (on a normalized scale).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are more concise ways, but here was my first thought:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  mutate(highest_yet = cummax(performance)) %>%
  arrange(-age) %>%
  mutate(highest_remaining = cummax(performance)) %>%
  filter(if_else(highest_yet < max(performance),
                 performance >= highest_yet,
                 performance >= highest_remaining)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(age, performance)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. It doesn't seem to plot the ggplot though, although the filtering indeed is done just the way I wanted!

Comment: I wonder if it would be easy to do this filtering by event as well? That is, if multiple events are included in the same data frame, with the event name in the column "event". Could I then loop through each event indiviually?

Comment: Sure, you could add `.by = event` in each mutate/filter, e.g. `mutate(highest_yet = cummax(performance), .by = event)` etc

Comment: Ok. Seems like this doesn't give each even-specific non-dominated data point for each event though

test2 <- top_by_age %>%
  mutate(highest_yet = cummax(speed), .by = event) %>%
  arrange(-age) %>%
  mutate(highest_remaining = cummax(speed), .by = event) %>%
  filter(if_else(highest_yet < max(speed),
                 speed >= highest_yet,
                 speed >= highest_remaining), 
         .by = event)